# Problemas com palavra reservada do PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

Prezados estou usando localmente um código baixado do GitHub para fins didáticos e estou tendo problemas em fazer o deploy do war, o erro tem a ver com uma palavra reservada do banco usada na tabela roles
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRO: erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a \\"authorization\\"

O Projeto faz uso do JSF, Hibernate ou seja é um projeto Web e como faz uso do JPA eu direcionei para o uso no banco Postgre originalmente ele é testado no MySQL 
Então minha pergunta é existe como resolver esta questão sem precisar alterar o banco?

Nota: o projeto é do Sr. Arthur Gregorio
https://github.com/arthurgregorio/web-budget

vou colocar algumas informações de classes

a) entidade

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@IdentityManaged(Role.class)
public class RoleTypeEntity extends AbstractIdentityTypeEntity {

   @Column(name = "authorization")
   private String authorization;
```

b) uma consulta

```
final List<Role> roles = queryBuilder.createIdentityQuery(Role.class)
            .where(queryBuilder.equal(Role.AUTHORIZATION, authorization)).getResultList();
```

c) uma classe mais não esta anotada ou seja não é uma entidade

```
@Named
@Dependent
public class Authorization {
```

Comment: Coloca o código da classe como erro ...

Comment: Authorization é uma palavra reservada no postgresql, veja qual classe está usando ela como nome de tabela e mude para outro nome. provavelmente deve estar usando a anotação @table("Authorization"), algo assim.

Comment: Não, não existe nenhuma classe de entidade ou seja anotada com @table conforme você exemplificou, vou editar a pergunta com mais informações sobre as classes do sistema.

Comment: É o nome da coluna authorization na classe RoleTypeEntity, muda o nome dessa coluna para outro nome para ver se funciona

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `delimited identifier` ou `quoted identifier` do PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS. Use: `@Column(name = "\"authorization\"")` para incorporar as aspas ao que é enviado para o PostgreSQL.

Comment: Por essas e outras que eu coloco um prefixo nos nomes dos campos e tabelas, todos os objetos do banco na verdade, evita concorrencia de nomes com palavras existentes

Answer (score 0):

> Então minha pergunta é existe como resolver esta questão sem precisar alterar o banco?

Sim, alterando o código. Modifica o nome da coluna onde tem a palavra reservada authorization:

```
@Column(name = "auth") // Muda o nome aqui!
private String authorization;
```

Isso deve resolver teu problema. Espero ter ajudado ^^